# Page for changing the look of Microsoft Sharepoint site returns blank

Tags: sharepoint

I was given a credential for a sharepoint site to change the theme of the existing site. However, it seems that the options for "Change the look", "Themes" and "Composed Looks" all return a blank page despite being a "site collection administrator".

From a little research, I've come to know that most probably, it might be because of a permission issue or URL mismatch. I'd be happy if somebody shed some light into this.

[image: Changing sharepoint site theme returns a blank page]

Answer (score 1):

You need to have either Site Owner or Designer or Site admin to change the look of the SharePoint site. Looks like currently you don't have these permissions.

The correct URL is `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/designgallery.aspx`

Reference - [Change the look of your SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-look-of-your-sharepoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818)

Comment: I've been assigned in the 'owners' group and it tells that I've Full Control. Do we still need specific designer or site admin or site owner permission?

Comment: Looks like you need to enable scripting in the site collection. Use the below powershell `Set-SPOSite https://sitecollurl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages `

Comment: also check [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/allow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f) to enable scripting on the tenant

Comment: You will need to check with your sharepoint admin to run this scripts

Comment: sure.. many thanks I've asked my admin to do so... will put forward the progress if any...